# Relational databases - to delete or not to delete?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, database, crud

Iv'e just heard from a colleague that deleting rows on a relational DB is pretty dangerous (regarding indexing and cascading actions)

He said that one solution for allowing deletions is to have a "deprecated" field for each entity and instead set the field to true in order to mark the row as "deleted".

of course that will require you on all your queries to fetch all the "dedicated" == false (which is pretty cumbersome)

My questions are:

1. Is he right? if so - what exactly is dangerous about deleting exactly?
2. Does his solution is a good practice?
3. Any alternatives to this solution are available?

thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/820489/477878

Answer (score 2):

If you have your schema well structured and use transactions where needed, deletions are perfectly safe and using deletion you will get far better performance than the approach you friend suggests.

Inserting a new element may get a tricky as deleting one. I wonder what hacky approach would your friend suggest to overcome that.

CRUD operations have been here for a long while now and creators of relational databases have done pretty good job in optimizing them. Any attempt to outsmart decades of gradual improvement with such hack will most probably fail.

Applying the solution your friend suggests may result in having a huge database with only a small fraction of non-deleted elements. This way your queries will become slower too.

Now having said all that I would like to support a little bit the other side. There are cases when the solution your friend suggests may be the only option. You can't change your schema everytime some query turns out to be slow. Also as others suggest in their answers if you use the "mark as deleted" approach deleted data will be recoverable(which may or may not be good again mentioned in other answers).

Comment: Not necessarily disagreeing, but why would it give better performance to delete? The lack of filtered indexes in MySQL?

Comment: I have first-hand experience with enormously slow batch deletions in a large table.

Comment: you are sure that it is not the databases structure that causes this slowness?

Comment: What do you mean by "database structure"? We are talking about deletion in a single table, no cascading.

Comment: @Marko Do you use transaction for your deletion ?

Comment: @sim Yes I do, and it can't be avoided because the table is involved in many other transactions.

Comment: @Marko And what was the solution ?

Comment: @sim Currently we are just living with the slowness, scheduling batch deletions for off-hours. I have other systems with the flagging approach and this has no performance difficulties. You must, of course, take care to involve the "deleted" column in all indexes. Batch undeletion will still be slow, for the same reasons that deletion is slow in the discussed case.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik I think that's what I meant. When you say `it can't be avoided because the table is involved in many other transactions` maybe you can improve that by changing the schema? Without knowing your particular case of course i am just speculating but it seems like it to me.

Answer (score 2):

This question has multiple layers. In general it is a good idea to mark rows as deleted instead of actually deleting them.

There are a few major benefits:

1. The data is recoverable. You can provide an undelete to users.
2. The update is faster than the delete.
3. In a publicly facing app none of the publicly interactable code has a true delete, making it much more difficult to use that code for inappropriate purposes (sql injection, etc.)
4. If you ever want to report in your data you can.

There are of course caveats and best practices:

1. This does not apply to lookup tables with easy to recreate data.
2. You need to consider culling. In our databases we cull deleted records into archival reporting tables. This keeps the primary tables fast, but allows us to report on data related to "deleted" items.
3. Your culling performance impact (at largish scale) will be similar to a backup and have similar considerations. Run them off hours if you want to archive them all at once, or periodically via cron if you want to just take X number per hour.
4. *NEVER* use the deleted data in your live data. In other words it is not a status flag! It is *gone*. I've made this mistake before and undoing it was painful.
5. If there is a very high percentage of deletes in a table ask yourself if keeping the data is actually important. You might adjust your culling process to not archive and to instead just run the actual delete.

This approach will last for a really really long time unless your dataset is massive and deletions are massive. Some architecture astronaut will ask you about what is going to happen when you archive 1 billion rows.... when you get to that point you are either hugely successful and can find another way, or you've screwed something else up so completely your archive tasks won't matter any more relative to the other issues you have.

Answer (score 1):

Dangerous?  Will the server or data center blow up?

I think your colleague is indulging in some hyperbole.

You need not cascade updates or deletes if you don't wish to, but it can be easier than having to clean up manually.   It's a choice that you make when you create your schema.

Marking rows as deleted using a flag is another way to go, but it's just another choice.  You'll have to work harder to find all the bad rows and run a batch job to remove them.

if you have retention requirements, it's more typical to partition the schema and move older records off into a warehouse for historical analysis and reporting.    In that case you wouldn't be deleting anything, just moving them out after a set period of time.

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes, he is right. Databases (indexes, specifically) are optimized for insertion and deletion can be painfully slow. Even setting an indexed field to null can cause the same trouble. I see cascading as a lesser issue because the db should never be configured to do dangerous cascading automatically.
2. Yes, flagging a record as "inactive", "deleted", "deprecated" (your choice) is standard and preferred practice to resolve a deletion-related performance issue.

   But, to qualify the above, it only applies to *transactional* (as opposed to *archival*) tables, and then only to those specific tables which contain a huge number of rows (millions and more). Do not ham-handedly apply a "best practice" across the board.
3. Another approach is to simply not have a transactional table with millions of rows. Move the data to an archival table before it grows to such proportions.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with `DELETE`'s in relational databases is that they are unrevertable. You delete data and it's gone. There is no way to restore it (except rollback to an earlier backup, of course). Combined with the SQL syntax, which is based on the principle "take everything I don't explicitely exclude" this can easily lead to unintentional loss of data due to user error or bugs.

Just marking data as deleted but not actually deleting it has the advantage that deleted data can be easily restored. But keep in mind that the marked-as-deleted pattern also has disadvantages:

- As you said, programming gets a bit more complicated, because you have to remember that every `SELECT` must now include a `WHERE deleted = false`.
- When you frequently delete data, your database will accumulate a lot of cruft. This will cause it to grow which impacts performance and uses unnecessary drive space.
- When your users are forced to delete data due to privacy regulations and they assume that pressing the "delete" button really deletes it, this practice might inadvertedly cause them to violate these regulations.

Comment: I think an updatable view may help with problem #1, although I've not personally tried that with MySQL.

Comment: +1 for writing everything I wanted to write, but way quicker :)