# sqlite3 "foreign key constraint failed"

Tags: sqlite, foreign-keys

I've set up two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE A
(
    id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    name TEXT
 );

CREATE TABLE B
(
    id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    id2 INTEGER,
    book TEXT,
    FOREIGN KEY(id2) REFERENCES A(id)
);
```

After I insert data into `A`, it looks like this:

```
1    John

2    Amy

3    Peter
```

After I insert data into `B`, it looks like this:

```
1     1     Lord of the Rings

2     1     Catch 22

3     2     Sum of All Fears

4     3     Hunt for Red October
```

I then execute the following statement:

```
delete from a where id=1;
```

I get the following: `"Error: foreign key constraint failed"`

I then restart `sqlite3` and try again but this time I enter this first:

```
PRAGMA foreign_keys = 1;
```

it still doesn't work......

Comment: Setting `PRAGMA foreign_keys = 1` actually enforces the foreign key constraint. I get the impression that you are trying to disable it, which means that you should be setting it to 0 instead of 1

Comment: Don't delete things, mark them as "dead". https://stackoverflow.com/questions/502501/database-to-delete-or-not-to-delete-records

Comment: Good example here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/47661573/2377343

Answer (score 36):

`Table B` has rows whose foreign key references the primary key value of the `Table A` row you are trying to delete so deleting it would violate the integrity of your database.

You could include `ON DELETE CASCADE` in your foreign key definition.  With that, when you delete an entry from `Table A`, any entries in `Table B` linked to the deleted row would also be deleted.  Don't know if that's appropriate for your application.

Comment: Also have a look at my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76840478/sqliteconstraintexception-foreign-key-constraint-failed-code-787

Answer (score 17):

The "problem" is that you have set a foreign key on table B.

```
foreign key(id2) references A(id)
```

This means that column `id2` in table B references column `id` in table A. Both `Lord of the Rings` and `Catch 22` from `Table B` are linked to `John` from `Table A`. Therefore you cannot delete `John` without first deleting these other two entries from `Table B` first.

The alternative would be to remove the foreign key.

See [this](http://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html) documentation for more details.

Comment: For some reason I had an impression that that should happen automatically. Isn't it what CASCADE settings is for?

Comment: @jayarjo you are correct. Kyle's answer contradicts the documentation he refers to.

Comment: Also have a look at my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76840478/sqliteconstraintexception-foreign-key-constraint-failed-code-787

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
CREATE TABLE A (
id   INTEGER NOT NULL
             PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
name TEXT);

CREATE TABLE B (
id   INTEGER NOT NULL
             PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
id2  INTEGER REFERENCES A (id),
book TEXT);
```

for delete :

```
PRAGMA foreign_keys = 0;
DELETE from A where id = 1;
PRAGMA foreign_keys = 1;
```

Comment: That does not fix the problem, it just ignores it. The deletion will not cascade, and leave you with a bunch of orphaned rows in table B.

Answer (score 0):

Check the data you are inserting in your foreign key. I got the same error, and it was to a bad data I inserted