# Error when I run rake test in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am getting an error when I try to run a test on my very simple app in ROR. I am taking a course online and I have this very simple database that has two tables: `posts` (with `title` and `body`) and `comments` (with ForeignKey: `post_id` and `body`. When I run `rake test` I get the following error:

```
Error: PostsControllerTest#test_should_destroy_post:
ActiveRecord::InvalidForeignKey: SQLite3::ConstraintException: FOREIGN
 KEY constraint failed: DELETE FROM "posts" WHERE "posts"."id" = ?
     app/controllers/posts_controller.rb:57:in `destroy'
     test/controllers/posts_controller_test.rb:43:in `block (2 levels) in <class:PostsControllerTest>'
     test/controllers/posts_controller_test.rb:42:in `block in <class:PostsControllerTest>'


bin/rails test test/controllers/posts_controller_test.rb:41

....

Finished in 12.539965s, 1.1164 runs/s, 1.2759 assertions/s. 14 runs,
16 assertions, 0 failures, 1 errors, 0 skips`
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15443913/sqlite3-foreign-key-constraint-failed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error occurs when you delete a row in a table whose primary key is referenced in another table.  You can include `ON DELETE CASCADE` in your foreign key definition (where you define where the primary key is referenced by another table), or add another delete statement to delete the row referencing the primary key, before doing the delete statement you are currently doing.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your `Post` model:

```
has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy
```

This will destroy associated comments when you will destroy your `Post` model. So you will not get `ConstraintException`.

You can find more info about Rails associations [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html).