# FOREIGN KEY constraint failed, SQLite

Tags: sql, sqlite, foreign-keys

I'm pretty new to databases and SQLite. I have a database that was provided to me, for an ASP.NET MVC web application to consume. I have to implement CRUD operations with Albums, Tracks, Artists and Media Types. Most of the functionality has been implemented and working as should, however, when implementing the delete operation for the *tracks table* I noticed an error, '[19:46:57] Error while deleting row from table tracks: FOREIGN KEY constraint failed'.

Could someone help me understand why I can not delete a row from the 'tracks' table without it violating a foreign key constraint, and which constraint it is violating.

Any assistance would be very much appreciated!

Here is a screenshot of the [ERD Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hXrLI.jpg), [Tracks Table Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2R4aR.jpg), [Tracks Table Constraints](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UMvdv.jpg) and [Sample Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jXFrC.jpg).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [sqlite3 "foreign key constraint failed"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15443913/sqlite3-foreign-key-constraint-failed)

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097) [Why are images of text, code and mathematical expressions discouraged?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/320052/266284) [mre] [ask] [Help]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that your issue is that the **track** is referenced by an **invoice_item** That is you likely have a Foreign Key definition for the **TrackID** column of the **invoice_items** table referencing the **TrackId** column of the **Tracks** table.

As highlighted :-

[image]

Regarding the comment

> all the foreign keys have 'ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION'

NO ACTION is the default i.e. you take NO ACTION when the conflict occurs so the conflict remains as it is and hence the error. Perhaps consider other actions as per https://sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html#fk_actions

Comment: Ah, that cleared things up! Much appreciated, thank you!