# What should I delete from my database?

Tags: database, security

More specifically, if I have a forum, should the administrator be able to delete completely ( wiping the database), or just set a hidden flag, when it comes to posts, boards or threads?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Database: To delete or not to delete records](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/502501/database-to-delete-or-not-to-delete-records)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Having a flag is always better approach than removing / deleting the record from database,
As it will be useful in many cases, such as,

1. -Accidental deletions
2. Data analysis
3. History prospective
4. Identifying spam users (in your case i.e. forum) etc.