# Delete a post in Django

Tags: python, django

I new to django and I am trying to make a web application. I have this page [page image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S8mjh.png) and I want to delete one post when I press the delete button. How can I do that? This is my modal for 'Post' :

```
class Post(models.Model):
    created_date = models.DateTimeField()
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    profile_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='poze', blank=True, null=True)
    text = models.CharField(max_length=1000, default='Nimic', blank=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

I've been looking for delete methods, but I've always found form-only methods and I don't use form. Thank you.

Comment: Use `Post.objects.filter(pk=post_id).delete()` to delete

Answer (score 8):

In you html :

```
<a href="{% url 'delete' p.id %}">Delete</a>
```

assuming that you are using a for loop  :

```
{% for p in posts %}
```

In your urls :

```
path('delete/<post_id>',views.delete_post,name='delete')
```

In your views :

```
def delete_post(request,post_id=None):
    post_to_delete=Post.objects.get(id=post_id)
    post_to_delete.delete()
    return HttpResponseRedirect(#name of the view function that returns your posts page)
```

And that's it

**EDIT**

This method deletes data from your database directly. So I recommend you add the @login_required decorator to your delete_post view function to protect your post. You can also make it accessible only for admin users or post owners in your html (Example : only users who have staff role can see the delete link)

```
{% if user.is_staff %}
<a ...>Delete</a>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: this is highly insecure because everybody could call these URLs and post would be deleted. at least add a "login_required" much better is to check the owner of the post and with an extra "if request.user = owner...delete()"

Comment: Sure, he will add those depending on his needs. I just explained the process and eventually that's what he asked for.

Comment: I edited my answer built on your comment, thank you.

Comment: yes just wanted to make it clear, some people simply "copy&paste" code and this piece here can be dangerous without any user authenticated checks. Glad you edited it :)

Comment: Totally agree !

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass argument with post id.  It would like something like this

```
p = Post.objects.get(pk=2)
p.delete()
```

Answer (score 1):

You should create a new field in the database table. Whenever you are deleting the data then you should change the delete field.

```
class Post(models.Model):
    created_date = models.DateTimeField()
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    profile_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='poze', blank=True, null=True)
    text = models.CharField(max_length=1000, default='Nimic', blank=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    delete_flag = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

And whenever you are should the data then you should filter the data on the delete flag

> Post.objects.filter(delete_flag=False)

Though it is subjective and I don't know you use case, but still as a beginner its better to start with this practice.

[Read More](https://stackoverflow.com/a/502525/4881398)

[Article 2](https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2010/09/03/sql-server-soft-delete-isdelete-column-your-opinion/)

Comment: To implement the safe deletion, Django-safedelete is a good choice.
https://github.com/makinacorpus/django-safedelete