# MySQL with Soft-Deletion, Unique Key and Foreign Key Constraints

Tags: mysql, database-design, foreign-keys, constraints

Say I have two tables, `user` and `comment`. They have table definitions that look like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `user` (
  `id`       INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `username` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  `deleted`  TINYINT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY (`username`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

```
CREATE TABLE `comment` (
  `id`      INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` INTEGER NOT NULL,
  `comment` TEXT,
  `deleted` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_comment_user_id` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`)
    REFERENCES `user` (`id`)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

This is great for enforcing data integrity and all that, but I want to be able to "delete" a user and keep all its comments (for reference's sake).

To this end, I've added `deleted` so that I can `SET deleted = 1` on a record. By listing everything with `deleted = 0` by default, I can hide away all the deleted records until I need them.

So far so good.

The problem comes when:

- A user signs up with a username (say, "Sam"),
- I soft-delete that user (for unrelated reasons), and
- Someone else comes along to sign up as Sam, and suddenly we've violated the UNIQUE constraint on `user`.

I want users to be able to edit their own usernames, so I shouldn't make `username` the primary key, and we'll still have the same problem when deleting users.

Any thoughts?

**Edit for clarification:** Added following RedFilter's answer and comments below.

I'm concerned with the case where the "deleted" users and comments are not visible to the public, but are visible only administrators, or are kept for the purpose of calculating statistics.

This question is a thought experiment, with the user and comment tables just being examples. Still, `username` wasn't the best one to use; RedFilter makes valid points about user identity, particularly when the records are presented in a public context.

Regarding "*Why isn't username the primary key?*": this is just an example, but if I apply this to a real problem I'll be needing to work within the constraints of an existing system that assumes the existence of a surrogate primary key.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Add unique constraint on fields(username, deleted)
Change field type for 'deleted' to INTEGER.

During delete operation (it can be done in trigger, or in part of code where you need actually delete user) copy value of id field to deleted field.

This approach allow you:

- keep unique names for active users (deleted = 0)
- allow delete users with same username several times

Field 'Deleted' can't have only 2 value because the following scenario will not work:

1. you create user 'Sam'
2. User Sam is deleted
3. You create new user witn userName 'Sam'
4. You try delete user with userName 'Sam' - fail. You already have record userName = 'Sam' and deleted = '1'

Comment: Changing the field type of `deleted` to `timestamp` would allow you to add more deleted rows there. if you want existing (not deleted) records, check for `null` in this field.

Comment: @TahaPaksu you would lose the value of the unique key if you allowed nulls in deleted.

Comment: @eric_s this approach needs to be designed like "Everything except 1 will be treated as 'not deleted'".

Comment: At least in PostgreSQL there's a way to reconcile both requirements - use a partial index, cf. [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/378331/physical-vs-logical-soft-delete-of-database-record#comment24914526_378355).

Comment: the idea could implement with a pair key on username and deletedAt too

Comment: @TahaPaksu Doesn't work with MySQL. since, it ignores null.

Comment: @Nikhil Where do you use null?

Comment: @TahaPaksu on the deleted column.

Answer (score 5):

Just keep the unique index or contraint on `username`. You do not want new users to be able to use the deleted name, as not only could there be general confusion about identity, but if you are still showing the old posts from the deleted user, then they will mistakenly be understood to be posted by the new user with the same name.

When a new user registers, you would normally check to see if the name is in use before allowing registration to complete, so there should be no conflict here.

.

Comment: @RedFilter, Its not a finished solution - you will not be able mark two 'Sam' as deleted. Think better copy Id to deleted field during deletion operation. This allow keep only one person as active, and have several deleted users with same name (by using constaint unique(name, deleted) ).

Comment: @Michael: I don't agree that two separate users should be able to use the same username.

Comment: @Michael: First reaction, "That's a hack". Second reaction, "Wow, that's actually pretty clever".  
Presumably you mean to set the constraint to `UNIQUE KEY (username, deleted)`.

Comment: @RedFilter: I'm concerned with the case where the "deleted" users and comments are not visible to the public, but are visible only administrators, or are only kept for the purpose of calculating statistics. Sorry to disagree, but I believe it's a valid case to consider.

Comment: @Rob: I maintain that it is a bad idea from a usability and community perspective to allow multiple non-concurrent users with the same username, even with the new information you have provided that the old users' information will be hidden. That does not erase them from the memory of the other users, and confusion can ensue.

Answer (score 1):

My practical solution for soft-delete is archiving by creating a new table with the following columns: `original_id`, `table_name`, `payload`, (and an optional primary key `id).

Where `original_id` is the original id of deleted record, `table_name` is the table name of the deleted record (`"user"` in your case), `payload` is JSON-stringified string from all columns of the deleted record.

I also suggest making an index on the column `original_id` for latter data retrievement.

By this way of archiving data. You will have these advantages

- Keep track of all data in history
- Have only one place to archive records from any table, regardless of the deleted record's table structure
- No worry of the unique index in the original table
- No worry of checking foreign index in the original table

The is already a discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2549940/1398479) explaining why soft-deletion is not a good idea in practice. Soft-delete introduces some potential troubles in the future such as counting records, ...

Answer (score 1):

We are using mysql generated column (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-generated-columns.html) to solve the problem.

```
ALTER TABLE `dummy` ADD `not_deleted` tinyint AS (if(`deleted_at` is null,1,NULL)) STORED;
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX `IDX_4b8d12e176ac3d69d21ebebd5a` ON `dummy` (`code`, `not_deleted`);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

```
 CREATE UNIQUE INDEX YourIndexName 
 ON YourTableName (Column1, Column2, Column3)
 WHERE IsDeleted = 0
```

You can find the complete answer here:

[enter link description here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/134187/unique-constraint-on-multiple-columns-and-soft-del.html)

Comment: does MySQL support that?

Comment: I think they changed the question title

Comment: Or I putted here to show how to do in SQL Server and forgot to mention