# What happens to related resources when a resource receives a DELETE request?

Tags: sql, api, rest

Let's say an API has the method `DELETE` for the endpoint `/authors/:id`, which also deletes all posts by said author.

I understand that, when an author is deleted from the database, all `GET` requests to `/authors/:id/posts` should respond with `410 GONE`, indicating that said resource is no longer available.

How should the API understand that the resource used to exist but no longer does? After all, the query `SELECT * FROM posts WHERE author_id = id;` is empty.

The only "solution" I thought of was to **not** delete the posts, but check the existence of the author in the database and act accordingly.

Comment: You can delete the posts but don't delete the Author just add a column named ``IsDeleted`` to Author table and check if IsDeleted=true then it's Gone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In most business applications, you don't *really* want to delete records during the normal flow of operation, especially if you then have to cascade those deletes.

For instance, in a finance application, when a customer stops doing business with you, you don't want to delete that customer record and all the sales in the past - you want to set a flag saying "this customer is no longer active".

That's often referred to as a [soft delete.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/378331/physical-vs-logical-hard-vs-soft-delete-of-database-record)

Your REST API can interpret the deleted status to issue the correct status code (`GONE`, rather than `NOT FOUND`)